# Start rails app from git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, templates

What do I need to do if I want to use https://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example as my starting point for my app?

I'm developing on OSx and I'm a noob.  I'd like to start with a pre-built auth system and go from there.  New to git too--I think I want to pull from git? or start a new rails app as a template?

Comment: Prereqs - do you have git installed?

Comment: Indeed! I've been fooling with it today--pretty nice. :)

Comment: I should have just answered, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use that. You need to install git. Check out homebrew to install git, makes life easier.

Next do

```
git clone https://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example.git

cd devise-omniauth-example
```

and you are good to go after changing some configs, mostly db.

I would recommend starting from scratch and reading about devise. It may take a bit longer, but will make life easier in the long run.

Comment: I did one devise walk-through, and got things running. I'm probably going to try to get the hang of git/heroku deployment before I start a real app--just fiddling right now. :)

Comment: ah gotcha. That is always fun, I tend to do that as well. Definitely have fun messing with heroku, it is a great service.

Answer (score 0):

In command line:

```
git clone git://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example.git
```

This will download the whole app you'll be able to use after configuring your database and having bundled the gemfile.